# Permission denied updating grub as root

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, permissions

I bought a MSI laptop recently and I struggled to install Ubuntu. Now I have it installed and I have two problems. One of the is that I need to modify the grub file but when I try(update-grub) it doesn't let me change the file it says this:

```
root@equipo-GL62-6QF:~# update-grub  
Generando archivo de configuración grub...
/etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy: 3: /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy: /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: Permission denied
```

These are the only changes I made into the grub file:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"
```

Does anyone know why is this happening? If I don't modify these lines I won't be able to shutdown the laptop without a crash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the specific file /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy. 
Press `Alt + F2` or open a terminal and run `gksu nautilus`. Browse to /etc/grub.d/bin/ and edit the permissions of grubcfg_proxy.

- It should run fine but if `sudo update-grub` displays error for some other file, repeat the process for that file.